# Docker file didn't execute CMD section

Tags: docker, cmd, dockerfile

Hi I want to build my dockerfile but I have problem with CMD in dockerfile. CMD not execute in docker build, but when I run docker with docker start ID it works. I have question how to execute CMD in build process. I have to manualy start container to execute CMD.

DOCKER FILE:

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install some depenendencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

# Default command
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

output form consol

```
iMac-PATRYK:simpleweb patryk$ docker build .
[+] Building 1.4s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                  1.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 91B                                                                0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine@sha256:597864180891b2498e104ace823507882aa9ae1321  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /usr/app                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY ./ ./                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] RUN npm install                                                                0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                          0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:ca6dfc810f02ea6a248685919c86d4889eb926ad78b64344b50e12ec7a51c95a    0.0s
iMac-PATRYK:simpleweb patryk$ docker run ca6dfc810f02ea6a248685919c86d4889eb926ad78b64344b50e12ec7a51c95a

> start
> node index.js

Listening on port 8080
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have to start the container. How else would you imagine the process to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD command is not suppose to run in the build process, it's a definition of what command to execute when starting a container from an image